# UTF-8 java encoding edge case

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic, non-ascii-characters

I am working with spring cloud Microservices to handle some medical messages that includes patients names in both English and Arabic, I am using the following code snippet that process the message:

```
@Override
public Message<?> mainTransformer(Message<?> message) {

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(message.getPayload().toString());
    String requestMessage = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer).toString();
    //Some processing.
    message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestMessage).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();

    return message;
}
```

Recently we noticed weird behavior with a single Arabic character "ف" that is not encoded correctly, we have tried multiple ways of encoding with same results, yesterday I noticed the same issue with a Russian character "с", and another one that I don't recognize "Ձ".

The issue here is that all of thee characters have an UTF-8 code pattern "U+**41", any character with such pattern being mapped to "�?".

The cloud server is running on Windows server, and the issue does not happen when running the processors as spring boot app directly from STS, and will happen when starting the apps as jars from java cmd, or from spring cloud stream.

I have added "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" when running the app but didn't help.

Comment: Why the encode/decode pattern? It's like zipping and then instantly unzipping, completely unnecessary and a potential source of bugs (although maybe not the source of this one).

Comment: Indeed, what you have there is the equivalent of `requestMessage = message.getPayload().toString()`. If there is any problem, it's probably in the way the payload is stored in the message, or the way `toString()` decodes it.

Comment: The message is commig from kafka topic, and the encoding/decoding lines are the best solution to have arabic characters printed correctly in both logs and output kafka topic, thought I have tried multiplr ways.

Comment: A side note, the issue is not there wjin starting the app from eclipse directly.